# Google maps Info Window Overlay content just like that in maps.goole.com

Tags: maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I want have the info window content for a marker just a s below

[image]

My code so far is

```
loadEmbeddedMap : function() {
        var script = document.createElement("script");
        script.type = "text/javascript";
        script.src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initEmbeddedMap";
        document.body.appendChild(script)
    },
    initEmbeddedMap : function() {
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40, -80);
        var myOptions = {
                zoom: 8,
                center: myLatlng,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("embeddedGoogleMap"), myOptions);
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': $('#userMapAddress').val()}, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    map: map, 
                    position: results[0].geometry.location
                });
                console.debug(results[0]);
                infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
                var infoWindowContent = "<div><strong>Address:</strong></div>";
                infoWindowContent    += "<div>"+results[0].address_components[0].short_name+","+results[0].address_components[1].short_name+"</div>";
                infoWindowContent    += "<div>"+results[0].address_components[5].short_name+","+results[0].address_components[7].short_name+"</div>";
                //infoWindowContent    += results[0].formatted_address;
                infowindow.setContent(infoWindowContent);
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            } else {
                //alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
            }
        });
        $('#embeddedGoogleMapWrapper').show();
    },
```

Code above outputs this

[image]

How to get those 'Directions', 'Search near by' stuffs..? Any helps appreciated..

Comment: Hi! I'm also looking for something similar but much simpler. I just want to include an active URL in my tooltip. By active i simply mean that a user should be able to click it to go to the required web page. Can you guide me on that? Thanks

Comment: Have you seen an infowindow like this somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

I would start by reading

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/localsearch/devguide.html#hiworld

As i can see it is possible to do what you want. I cant get you a straight answer but maybe a clue.
I would create my own form in infowindow at least pretty close to the original google one and handle click events by sending those search queries. 
Than you need to handle search results

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/localsearch/devguide.html#handle_search_results

Do some testing with

http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#the_hello_world_of_local_search

For example you can get lat from localSearch.results[i].lat and so on.

I hope you can get something out of this