# Twitter Bootstrap and Google Maps - Rendering Problems

Tags: jquery, twitter, twitter-bootstrap, maps

I'm currently trying to implement something using both Google Maps and Twitter Bootstrap on the same page, and I have ran into an issue using modals over a Google Maps body.

Here's my current development snapshot:
http://getmerch.scootaloo.at/snapshot-2012-12-27.php

Normally the "More info ..." button inside the GMaps InfoWindows should open a Bootstrap modal, but it won't.
The same button code will work if not displaying a maps canvas (removing the maps canvas is enough - the actual Maps JScript code doesn't need to be removed).

The InfoWindows are also rendered incorrectly.

Do you guys have any idea how I could fix this?

Thanks in advance.

-- Kenny

Comment: Hmmm...I am not sure why the packing of the info balloon, but you must have a reason.  Have you considered converting that to an HREF and iFrame pop a lightbox with what ever additional info you need? Also, how many pins will your map have?  1 or 2 or thousands?  It might be problematic from a usability perspective, but I am guessing at what your goal is.

Comment: I would be fine with anything, actually. I'm not very experienced with the Google Maps API so far, so I'm trying to combine things I already know. I'd like to have a small popup over every map point that shows a short description, with a button that allows me to open a detailed description box. It shouldn't have more than ten to twenty map points. The point of this is basically to show different stores on the map, with item availability data displayed using an icon on the map, and with a mouseover box that shows a short description of what is in stock.

Comment: Ok then pop over to the Google V3 API stuff.  You are interested in this stuff: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows ...ok head over to the demo gallery https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/demogallery  ...see if you can follow along this stackoverflow post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3921823/google-maps-info-window-overlay-content-just-like-that-in-maps-goole-com it has that robust overlay and info balloon stuff you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following css on your map div:

```
#map img {
  max-width: none;
}
```

This fixed my bootstrap / gmaps image issues.